# How do I do an Ajax update_attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am decent at Rails but am completely lost when it comes to JavaScript and Ajax.

I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks on an item in a list, an `update_attributes` is called using Ajax on that item.

Here is what I've got so far, but it's terrible and I am completely lost.

In the view:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "entry", data: {url: update_seen_count_url} do %>
    <h5><a href="#"><%= simple_format user_notification.content %></h5> 
<% end %>
```

`update_seen_count` (refered to in the data attribute above) refers to this controller action:

```
class UserNotificationsController < ApplicationController
    def update_seen_count
        ... (I think something like @usernotification.update_attributes but i have no idea)
    end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the user to click on a specific link. To make it work use the `link_to` helper and add the `remote` attribute. For example:

```
<%= link_to simple_format(user_notification.content), update_seen_count_url, remote: true %>
```

Then you can tailor the response by using `respond_to do |format|` in your controller and adding an `action.js.erb` file to change the UI through javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this.  How do I pass to the controller what was clicked on?  Meaning, how do I tell it what to update_attributes on?

Comment: Simply add it to the url as a parameter as `update_seen_count_url(param)`. Make sure your routes reflect this.

Comment: Great, thanks!  This almost works, but the server logs return the following error: 'ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template user_notifications/update_seen_count, application/update_seen_count'.  I think its because the controller doesn't redirect anywhere in the controller, but thats because I don't want to.   Do you know how to get rid of that error?

Comment: Also, I am actually trying to figure out how to make it redirect.  For some reason, if i put a redirect in the update_seen_count action, it does not work unless i delete remote: true.  any ideas?

Comment: The redirect needs to be handled in your response. So in your `update_seen_count.js.erb` file do something like `window.location = '<%= redirect_path %>';`. If you remove `remote: true` it is no longer using AJAX hence why it works.

Comment: One last thing, if redirects is what you are after. You should rethink whether you need AJAX at all. The point is to make server side calls with no client side interruption and partial updates to the page.

Comment: Basically, I have a box in the middle of the page and i want to use ajax to change it from one view to another, so I don't think window.location will work.  any ideas?

Comment: Sure, put the box in a partial. Then render it on the response `$("<%= escape_javascript(render partial_name) %>").appendTo("#target_view");`. If your `target_view` is another page then AJAX is definitely not what you need.

Comment: When you say another page, do you mean if the target_view is in a different view or if the partial_name is something different?

Comment: Yes, `target_view` in a different view. Each `view` in the Model-View-Controller pattern is just an HTML page that gets spit out through the framework.

Comment: I've got a new question similar to this one.  Mind taking a look?  I think you'll know the answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982204/rails-make-link-work-with-ajax

Answer (score 0):

First of all define a route for your Ajax call:

```
  post "/my_controller/update_data" => "my_controller#update_data", :as => :update_data
```

Then in your view, do the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<%= update_data_path %>",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { update_attr_name : update_attr_name, new_value : var}
    })
    .done(function(resp){
        // when the controller responds
        // you can "play" with the response for the controller
        // for example if resp.my_status == "updated"
    })
    .fail(function(){
       // when the response from the controller is not a JSON or a header error (4**, 5**)
    })
    .always(function(){
       // run always
});
```

Finally your controller:

```
def update_data
 # you can retrieve here params[:update_attr_name] and params[:new_value]
 # then you can working on it, this should work:
 # mod = Model.update_attributes(params[:update_attr_name].to_sym => params[:new_value])

 # if ok
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render json: {:my_status => "updated", :data => "my_data"}}
    end
 # if something goes wrong: fail the Ajax call
rescue Exception => e
  puts "Exception #{e.message}"
  render :nothing => true, :status => 500
end
```

Personally I prefer this manner, because let the developer more "power" and flexibility in the process.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this.  How do I pass to the controller what was clicked on?  Meaning, how do I tell it what to update_attributes on?

Comment: @Philip7899 you can pass a params in the ajax call, I will update my answer