# Rails - make link work with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a link that should use ajax to load a partial next to it without reloading the page.  Here is the link:

```
<%= link_to 'test ajax link', profile_form_path , remote: true %>
```

Here is the controller that the link should go to:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
    def profile_form #the action is currently static so there is nothing in the controller
    end
end
```

And here is the js view that the controller action goes to:

profile_form.js.erb

```
$('.tab-edit-profile').html("<%= j render 'profile_form_p' %>");
```

However, it does not work.  The browser returns this error:

```
Template is missing
Missing template profiles/profile_form
```

Here is the line in the routes file:

```
get 'profile_form', to: 'profiles#profile_form'
```

If I change the file name to profile_form.html.erb, the page loads but not using ajax obviously.  Can anyone tell me the correct way to use ajax to implement this?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your route for this? It's likely that the HTTP verbs aren't lining up.

Comment: Sure, just posted it.  Thanks.

Comment: You receive a request as HTML format, and you have a .js.erb file (ERB file which generates a JS file at the end), that's why Rails is complaining: to respond to HTML format, he is looking for `profile_form.html.erb`. You can create this file and insert by yourself the script tags: `<script type="text/javascript">$('.tab-edit-profile').html("<%= j render 'profile_form_p' %>");</script>`

Comment: @MrYoshiji , Thanks, but that won't work because then the view won't load via ajax and the entire page will go to the link.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you need is a partial, for example, `_profile.html.erb`. The underscore tells Rails this file is rendered as partial. In your `profile_form.js.erb` you can try.

```
$('.tab-edit-profile').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'profile') %>");
```

That should get you going with static content. For dynamic, setup a `@profile` instance variable and try.

```
$('.tab-edit-profile').html("<%= escape_javascript(render @profile) %>");
```

Be sure to use `render json: @profile` in your controller response.

Answer (score 1):

From what you posted above, that should work correctly. The only thing I can think of is that you're not including the required javascript libraries and the `link_to` helper is not actually making an AJAX request.

You indicated that you're using Rails 4 so I'm assuming you're also using the Asset Pipeline. Please ensure that you have the following lines in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

and that the javascript is being included in the layout being used by the `ProfilesController`. Assuming the layout is `application.html.erb`, ensure that you have

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

in the `<head>` section of your layout.